# how to update table after inserting in another table in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

here is my php file...
i want to update first table after successful insertion in second table,i am to select and insert properly but the row which i want to update is not getting updated after the data is inserted.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        $full_name=$_POST['full_name']; 
        $email_address=$_POST['email_address'];
        $contact_number=$_POST['contact_number'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $location=$_POST['location'];
        $standard=$_POST['standard'];
        $institute=$_POST['institute'];
        $code=$_POST['code'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM activations WHERE code='$code' AND status='not used'";
        $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$sql));
        if(isset($check)==null)
            {
                echo  'exist';
            }
        else
            { 
                $sql1="INSERT INTO students(full_name, email_address, contact_number, gender, location, standard, institute)             VALUES('$full_name','$email_address','$contact_number','$gender','$location','$standard','$institute')";
            }
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)==true)
            {
                $sql2="UPDATE activations SET status='in use' WHERE code='$code';

    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

can any one tell me how to write this in php mysqli procedural way.

Comment: `if(isset($check)==null)` is not correct, it should just be `if ($check)`.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on the `$sql2` assignment line.

Comment: You never call `mysql_query()` on `$sql2`.

Comment: i refereed the syntax here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: if(isset($check)==null) is working for me, i am able to check condition there but it fails to update

Comment: No, it's not working, you're confused. When a row is fetched, `$check` will contain an array. `isset($check)` will then be `true`, and `true == null` will fail.

Comment: It fails to update because you never do `mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)`.

Comment: You're also missing a double quote after `WHERE code='$code'`. But that's obviously a copying error, because otherwise your script wouldn't run at all.

Comment: Oh, I see. It works because you want to say `exist` when the select *doesn't* find anything. Your logic is very confusing. Just write `if (!$check)` or `if ($check == false)`

Comment: i tried after giving double quotes but still fails to update and tried after removing iisset($check) still fails to update

Comment: how should i check condition before updating in place of mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)

Comment: You're checking the condition OK.

Comment: yeahh that's bit confusing, i have changed that as suggested by you

Comment: yes if the data is inserted then update the table

Comment: After you figure this out, you should go learn to use prepared queries.

Comment: there are 2 tables activations and students,first i am selecting from activations then inserting in students and finally i want to update activations table after the insertion is successful

Comment: yes actually i am new to all this concepts and trying to learn

Comment: can you tell me how can i update that

Comment: If you call `mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)` it should update that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `mysqli_query()` to perform the `UPDATE`.

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) {
    $sql2="UPDATE activations SET status='in use' WHERE code='$code'";
    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
        echo "Error updating activations: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} else {
    echo "Error inserting student: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```